How can MMA recognize graphics correctly?
For this figure, the middle position is a point

How does this code identify multiple points in the middle?
MorphologicalGraph[Binarize@ColorNegate@img, 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]



Does this answer your question? Merge vertexes that are close together in MorphologicalGraph Also: How to ensure that MorphologicalGraph produces a planar graph?
